# Pass ZMQ context to thread

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

In C++ I'm using ZeroMQ to build a simple client-server chatting application. Once the context is initialised in the main, I'd like to pass it to a thread and declare there the socket used to output the messages of the user (i.e. to perform the **send**). This is my current code (client/user side):

```
void Send(zmq::context_t& c ) // To get messages from user and send them to the server
{
    zmq::socket_t socket(c, ZMQ_REQ);
    socket.connect ("tcp://192.168.1.84:5555");

    std::string mssg;

    while (true) {

        std::getline(std::cin, mssg);

        if(mssg == "#exit")
        {
            killApp = true; // an atomic<bool> used to terminate all threads
            break;
        }
        zmq::message_t mssg_(mssg.length());
        std::memcpy(mssg_.data(), mssg.data(), mssg.length());

        socket.send(mssg_);

   }

}

int main ()
{
    // Initialising the context
    std::shared_ptr<zmq::context_t> context = std::make_shared<zmq::context_t>(1);
    std::thread t_send(Send, *context.get()); // THIS DOESN'T WORK

    {
       // do some stuff in the main thread (e.g. display the messages)
    }

    t_send.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to pass the context by reference to the thread so I can create a socket and perform the rest of the operation. But I don't know how to do it properly. (alternatively, passing a zmq::socket_t is also fine, but I'm facing the same issue trying to do that).

Comment: "I'm facing the same issue" - your question would be considerably better if you actually stated what that "same issue" is, and what problems you're having with it.

Comment: I don't recommend zmq as a starter framework. It wraps the socket API so much that you won't understand what's going on. Plus it still loses the first message in TCP comm. Use boost asio instead. You will learn concepts that are fundamental to network IO.

Comment: In Zmq you can share contexts but *never* sockets between two threads. And why not (in your original code):                                                      `zmq::context_t context (1); 
std::thread t_send(Send, context);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I've solved it: Passing the context as a *void* *pointer* and then casting it back to *zmq::context_t*:

```
void Send(void* context ) // To get messages from user and send them to the server
{ 
    zmq::socket_t s(*(zmq::context_t*)context,ZMQ_REQ);
    s.connect ("tcp://192.168.1.84:5555");
    ...
    ...
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<zmq::context_t> context = std::make_shared<zmq::context_t>(1);
    std::thread t_send(Send, static_cast<void*>(context.get()));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Comment: I am that someone! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find some samples in [zmqHelper](https://github.com/cibercitizen1/zmqHelper). There is an example of a chat, many threads communicating through inproc sockets (sharing the context), and a server with workers (also connected by inproc).